# How can I append new data from a particular mySQL table to an excel spreadsheet?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, export, excel

We have a database trigger that automatically adds new clients to a table when they first contact the server, it takes a number of unique identifiers that the client provides on first contact and stores them, things like processor number, mac address, firmware version, etc...

We want this data exported to an excel file. The current plan is that an excel file will be created and new clients added as they appear on the system, then once a specific number of clients have been added (we'll usually do it in batches) we'll take a copy of that file and delete the one on the server until the next time we want to add new clients.

I'd be grateful if any of you could point me towards some resources to show me  how to do this with mySQL / Mariadb.
I've found many solutions for importing excel files into the database, and a few about exporting to excel automatically from Microsoft SQL Server, but nothing about doing the same in mySQL, although I'll admit I haven't been looking very long. Anyway, any pointers you may have would be greatly appreciated. Also, just thinking, comma delimited text files may be good enough too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed my plan, instead of outputting to an excel file I'm going to build a web app that presents the requested data to the user, provides the ability to modify it if required along with the functionality to export to excel or csv format.